# Store variable number of argument to reuse in another macro

Tags: macros, tabularx, parameters

I am a begginner in Latex and I am trying to build a macro in latex with multiple parameters. So far, I have succeeded to write a macro that accepts multiple parameters (with the help of this website) :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\arrayGeneration}[1]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
   Col 1  & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col5 \tabularnewline \hline
  \lineScanFive#1\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
  \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand{\lineScanFive}[5]{%
  \ifx\relax #1 \empty
  \else
     #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\ \hline
    \expandafter\lineScanFive
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\arrayGeneration{
{elt1}{elt2}{elt3}{elt4}{elt5}
{elt6}{elt7}{elt8}{elt9}{elt10}
}
\end{document}
```

But now, I want to the macro arrayGeneration to use a parameters that were previously defined in another macro. However, my new Latex file wont compile (*Argument of \lineScanFive has an extra }*):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\arrayGeneration}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
   Col 1  & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col5 \tabularnewline \hline
  \lineScanFive{storeParameter}\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
  \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand{\lineScanFive}[5]{%
  \ifx\relax #1 \empty
  \else
     #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\ \hline
    \expandafter\lineScanFive
  \fi
}

\newcommand\storeParameter[1]{\newcommand\generationParam{#1}}

\begin{document}
\storeParameter{{elt1}{elt2}{elt3}{elt4}{elt5}
{elt6}{elt7}{elt8}{elt9}{elt10}}
\arrayGeneration
\end{document}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Is there a real advantage of `{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}` over ``a & b & c & d & e \\ f & g & h & i & j``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\arrayGeneration}{%
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
   Col 1  & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col5 \tabularnewline \hline
  \expandafter\lineScanFive\generationParam\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
  \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand{\lineScanFive}[5]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
  \else
     #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\ \hline
    \expandafter\lineScanFive
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\generationParam}{}
\newcommand\storeParameter[1]{\renewcommand\generationParam{#1}}

\begin{document}
\storeParameter{{elt1}{elt2}{elt3}{elt4}{elt5}
{elt6}{elt7}{elt8}{elt9}{elt10}}
\arrayGeneration
\end{document}
```

but I see no real advantage over direct input.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I still have a lot to learn…